# "Save as" in Excel 2019 is not offering to save in CSV format

Tags: ms-office, csv

I hit *File | Save As* and the output formats are only derivatives of the XLS. Why aren't CSV (and PDF etc) offered?

[image]

I am on excel 2019 for MacOS

[image]

Comment: Is this for all xlsx files or just particular one? If particular, please upload it somewhere and provide a link for us in the question.

Comment: @Gilby  It has  confidential data . it has multiple tabs and looks like some involved layout features.  I just wanted to pull the data into the csv and ignore the formatting/layout aspects.

Comment: It is probable that the complexity of the document is the problem here. Most likely that saving as CSV will actually *lose data.* You could copy each sheet and paste as text into another text editor. And saving as a PDF is offered in **ANY** Mac app that can print. Select print, and notice the drop down menu at the bottom left of the print dialog box. That is why MS doesn't offer a Print to PDF driver in Office, Apple already has.